# SublimeClang compiles as C, even in .cpp files

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, clang++

I'm trying to make the SublimeCLang plugin work on SublimeText 2. I have followed the install instructions, including the ctypes workaround and compiling libcache.

The plugin works, but I noticed that its compiling as C, even if I'm using C++ files. For example, given this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct vector2
{
    float x , y; 
};

int main()
{
    vector2 v;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; ++i)
        std::cout << i; 
}
```

the following errors are reported:

> /usr/include/c++/4.9.2/iostream:38,10 - Fatal - 'bits/c++config.h' file not found
>   Did you configure the include path used by clang properly?
>   See http://github.com/quarnster/SublimeClang for more details on how to configure SublimeClang.
>   /.../main.cpp:12,2 - Error - must use 'struct' tag to refer to type 'vector2'
>   /.../main.cpp:17,7 - Error - expected expression

I have tried to enable the `add_language_option` on SublimeClang.sublime-settings`, then passing`-x c++`on the`settings` array, but there is no change.
This is my complete settings file:

```
// Whether or not the plugin is enabled. Useful if you want to disable
// the plugin completely for a specific project.
"enabled": true,
// Whether or not to hide the clang output panel when it's empty
"hide_output_when_empty": true,

// Delay in ms until recompiling the file after the buffer is modified
// Set to 0 to disable.
// You probably also want to change the reparse_use_dirty_buffer
"recompile_delay": 0,

// Whether or not to inhibit the Sublime Text 2 built in word completions
"inhibit_sublime_completions": false,

// Whether to use the saved file or the (possibly) dirty buffer contents when reparsing
"reparse_use_dirty_buffer": false,

// Whether or not fast completions are enabled. Usually you'd put
// "sublimeclang_enable_fast_completions": false, in the project
// settings if it's problematic in that project. You can also
// runtime toggle fast completions alt+d,alt+f, however if it
// is disabled for the current project (or globally in your
// user settings) it will not be enabled. In other words
// this setting, when set to false, overrides whatever the
// keyboard toggle is set to.
"enable_fast_completions": false,

// When set to true will output the final options used to the python console
"debug_options": false,

// Number of worker threads to create. If set to -1 it'll create
// one thread per cpu
"worker_threadcount": 8,

"add_language_option":true,

"additional_language_options":
{
    // For example, you can use "c++": ["-std=c++11"] to enable C++11 features.
    "c++" : ["-std=c++11"]
},

"options":
[
    "-isystem", "/usr/include/c++/4.9.2",
    "-Wall",
    "-x c++"
]
```

**Is there a way to tell sublimeClang to compile as C++ instead of C?**